# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Puli Factory is not available' while sending mail using mailgun

Tags: php, guzzle, mailgun

I'm trying to send mail using the following code and I'm using `guzzlehttp`, but getting `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException'` with the message `'Puli Factory is not available'`. Please help me find a solution, thanks!

Here is my code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = new Mailgun('key-');
$domain = "domain";

# Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage("$domain",
              array('from'    => 'Mailgun Sandbox      <xxxxxx@sandbox.mailgun.org>',
                    'to'      => 'John Doe<xxxxx@abc.com>',
                    'subject' => 'Hello John Doe',
                    'text'    => 'Email Text'));
```

and i've replaced key and domain with my original.

Comment: Haven't your found this solution? https://github.com/php-http/discovery/pull/39

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.

Try:

```
$client = new \Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client(); 
$mailgun = new \Mailgun\Mailgun('api_key', $client);
```

Then:

```
$mailgun->sendMessage(.....)
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: You will need to pull guzzle 6 for it to work. (php composer.phar require php-http/guzzle6-adapter:^1.0)

Comment: Will this also work with Guzzle 5 as I only have php 5.4?